# Azure: Why is JavaScript STT-SDK from a default microphone just for PC, but not for mobile phones?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

The Azure JavaScript-STT-SDK works well on PC, but it does not work on mobile phones.

const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput()

```
//code
speech() {
      let that = this;
      const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
        "*******",
        "*******"
      );
      speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "zh-CN";
      const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
      const recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
      recognizer.start;
      recognizer.recognizeOnceAsync(result => {
        switch (result.reason) {
          case ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            console.log(`RECOGNIZED: Text=${result.text}`);
            that.inputMsg = result.text;
            console.log("    Intent not recognized.");
            break;
          case ResultReason.NoMatch:
            console.log("NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
            that.tts("没有听到您说话喔~");
            break;
          case ResultReason.Canceled:
            const cancellation = CancellationDetails.fromResult(result);
            console.log(`CANCELED: Reason=${cancellation.reason}`);
            if (cancellation.reason == CancellationReason.Error) {
              console.log(`CANCELED: ErrorCode=${cancellation.ErrorCode}`);
              console.log(
                `CANCELED: ErrorDetails=${cancellation.errorDetails}`
              );
              console.log("CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
            }
            break;
        }
      });
    },
```

Comment: " it does not work on mobile phones" < what kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

For now, to use it in microphone you need to use the browser SDK, for a sample you could refer to this doc: [Recognize speech from a microphone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/speech-to-text-from-microphone?tabs=dotnet%2Cx-android%2Clinux%2Cjava-runtime%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-javascript).

**Node:** when you test with the browser, it doesn't work on the Safari browser.  On Safari, the sample web page needs to be hosted on a web server; Safari doesn't allow websites loaded from a local file to use the microphone.